# Make one of two properties a must in a typescript interface

Tags: typescript

Basically what I'm looking for is pretty simple but I can't find the right answer, there's an answer using `type` but that's a no-go in my case. Basically, I need my class to implement an interface where one of two properties is a must. It should be any of them but at least one of them should be there. So if a class implementing this interface has one of them or both of them it's all good but if none of them properties are there then it's a "bad" class.

Is it achievable in typescript or not?

Here is the class that needs to implement the interface.

```
export class SetNewPasswordDto implement IPassTokenValidation {
    @ApiProperty()
    recoveryEmail: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsString()
    @IsAlphanumeric()
    passToken: string;
}
```

The `PassTokenValidation` interface in a certain sense indicates, which param will be used for the passToken validation. If it's `recoveryEmail` then the `SetNewPasswordDto` class should have the `recoveryEmail` prop, another param may be `phoneNumber`. What I want is that if the both params (`phone`, `recoveryEmail`) are absent then we have an error saying that the class incorrectly implements interface `IPassTookenValidation`;

Comment: what kinds of properties is it? Any examples?

Comment: yeah gimme a minute I will describe it in more detail.

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 Please, check out the update in the question.

Comment: you want your class either have ```recoveryEmail``` or ```passToken``` as props passed in?

Comment: As far as I know you can do it with types but not interfaces and classes can only implement interfaces. With types you just do one where one is mandatory and the other optional and another type where the reverse is true and then you OR them.

Comment: If you accept [F-bounded generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) then maybe [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHt0GcUG9kAeA-AFzJZhSgDmANMgJ6nmU3IC+AsAFCiSyIUAMXRQARsAAmkiCGT5iZEBABu0ekyWroHHn2jwkyALKhgAWzgAbeYTIUqIagG5d3HmAYAHFAHkA1nAMADwAKsgQBJAgklhomDgAfMgAvMjhkdGxyCLiUjJyRCZmljZkoTw8CFZwWHEA4piSABrIFl5WEOayYHEBQcGN6C3JCqnIAEQTbtW1DU0Amm3mHV09fYEhQ5ILo4zjUzM1dcjbzUvtnd3gGwNnu7YEBxOuDM9Hc8gAQnCSy6vXXrIfohH6SPbsZAAeihESgUFEAEIeDCALSo5IAP2xKNhAGFjnEAORgoltEAIURQCAIMBWN6XNY3cn8QwoImmEAWaxEgB0QA) works for you?